# Major bugs in SWFAddress

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript-3, swfaddress

I found a couple of rather glaring bugs in SWFAddress, involving IE-based browsers. Both of the following occurred in SlimBrowser (15,000,000 downloads on Cnet) and one in Avant (also several million downloads on Cnet).

Both bugs occur when returning to the original startup screen of a flex app via the back button.  Both of them are repeatable using the already compiled sample Flex app that comes with the most recent SWFAddress 2.4 full download (but I have also repeated them after recompiling, and with other flex apps as well.)

Bug 1:
Open SlimBrowser and then open the SWFAddress Flex sample app in a single tab (make sure all other tabs are closed).  In the flex sample app click one of the menu bar selections just to take it to another screen.  Now hit the browser back button to return to the original screen.  Then right-click the browser window tab for the Flex app and select 'close', to attempt to close the Flex app browser window.  It causes the browser to crash.

Bug 2:
Modify the code for the starting page of the Flex sample app mentioned above to include a hyperlink to some other website.  Now repeat the steps from Bug 1 to go to a different page of the sample app, and then return to the starting page via the back button. (Makes no difference this time if other browser tabs are opened.) Now click the hyperlink you created to navigate to some other site.  On the other site the back button is disabled and you can't return to the Flex sample app.

I can of course attempt to debug this myself.  Just didn't know if anyone wanted to save me the trouble.  Also is anyone still maintaining SWFAddress, and do they even care about this sort of thing.  I know people tend to loathe IE so don't know if they just decided not to support it. Also it would include scores of 3rd party browsers that have nothing to do with Microsoft, other than using the IE engine behind the scenes.

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is here.  Are you looking for validation?  A solution?

Comment: yeah - a solution would be great - haven't really delved into the code yet.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you add a new issue on the swfadress [bugtracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=181584&atid=897787)?